# htop CPU usage information does not look consistent

Tags: linux, performance-monitoring, cpu-usage, htop

Please have a look at htop screenshot below

[image]

You can see there that current host has two CPU cores (or CPUs).

All processes are ordered by CPU usage descending.

So how is it possible that with two processes eating 10% of CPU summary info shows that each of CPU core is loaded more than 50%?

System info: CentOS 5, DigitalOcean

UPDATE

Kernel threads are not hidden in `htop` settings.

`top` was showing alike information when ordered by CPU usage (in detail it showed that CPU is significantly loaded by system (~50%) and top processes in its list were using <10% summarized)

This was fixed by server reboot but it is still interesting why that may happen.

Comment: The only thing I see of note in your picture is that the majority of the cpu load is from kernel process(es)

Comment: Yes, I also can see that but those kernel processes consume 0% as per htop.

Comment: Same problem on Digital ocean too, but not solved by reboot :/ any clue?

Comment: It's an old question, but I have the same problem from time to time. Did you found something?

Answer (score 2):

Kernel processe is hidden by default in htop.
You can use shift-k to show kernel processes. 
(red in cpu usage bar is for kernel usage)